# How to parse nested JSON string using .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, json, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to parse a nested JSON string returned from the GCM (Google Could Messaging) server using VB.NET. The JSON string looks like this:

```
{ "multicast_id": 216,
  "success": 3,
  "failure": 3,
  "canonical_ids": 1,
  "results": [
    { "message_id": "1:0408" },
    { "error": "Unavailable" },
    { "error": "InvalidRegistration" },
    { "message_id": "1:1516" },
    { "message_id": "1:2342", "registration_id": "32" },
    { "error": "NotRegistered"}
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the **results** array in the above string.

I found the following example helpful, [example](http://www.offsight.co.uk/tutorials/web-development/asp.net/parse-json-from-a-string-or-post-in-asp.net-vb/) but it does not show how to get to the nested parts, specifically **message_id**, **error** and **registration_id** inside the **results** array.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give an answer using c# and [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```

You can also use  [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
var jobj2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Response>(json);
```

---

```
public class Result
{
    public string message_id { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
    public string registration_id { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int multicast_id { get; set; }
    public int success { get; set; }
    public int failure { get; set; }
    public int canonical_ids { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @KashifB use [Telerik's Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to translate the C# to VB.NET

Comment: Multicast Id and others should be long - int is too small for what google sends back