# extract and format value in JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I just started working with JSON strings. i have an array of json strings that contains json strings like

> {"ID":"3", "LinkFilename":"Test.txt", "Sender":"abc@hotmail.com", "Created":"2014-07-07T20:13:18.000Z"}

what i want to do is to take change the value of "Created" key (which is a date) and omit its time part so it must show only date part. i want to produce something like:

> {"ID":"3", "LinkFilename":"Test.txt", "Sender":"abc@hotmail.com", "Created":"2014-07-07"}

The code to produce Json is as follows:

```
 var ItemsEntries = [];
 var listItemInfo = '';
        var itemsCount = this.collListItem.get_count();
        for (i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
            var item = this.collListItem.itemAt(i);
            var ItemEntry = JSON.stringify(item.get_fieldValues());
            ItemsEntries.push(ItemEntry);
             listItemInfo += ItemsEntries[i].toString(); + '\n';
        }
```

Please guide me through this.

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629487/how-to-parse-nested-json-string-using-net

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Javascript object:

```
var item = {
  "ID":"3", 
  "LinkFilename":"Test.txt", 
  "Sender":"abc@hotmail.com", 
  "Created":"2014-07-07T20:13:18.000Z"
}
```

and you want to change the `Created` field in the way you described, you can first create a new `Date` object out of the `Created` field value and just extracting the pieces you care about with the functions included in the `Date` API (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

This code should be able to change `obj` to the format you require:

```
var formatItem = function(item){
  var date = new Date(item["Created"]);
  var formattedDate = date.getFullYear() 
                    + '-'
                    + date.getMonth() + 1 // zero-based index...
                    + '-'
                    + date.getDate();
  item["Created"] = formattedDate;
};
```

One caveat is that the month won't be padded on the left by a 0 if it's a single digit, but that's easy enough to fix on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: cant substr() be used to get the desired string once the "created" field is gotten??

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider Sure, you can just set `item["Created"]` to `item["Created"].substr(0, 10)`. I prefer the approach I took for superficial reasons (it won't work for dates past the year 10,000 for example!) but the substring thing should work for all reasonable inputs.